# Python: is it possible to infer the possible exceptions that a function can raise?

Tags: python, exception, pylint, mypy, astroid

I was trying to document the possible errors that could occur as a result of a remote procedure call (RPC).

It occurred to me that it might be nice if you could do this with a little magic. Is there anything in python to infer possible exceptions (kinda like checked exceptions in java).

I'm a little afraid of how complicated `astroid` and friends can be though...

I'm thinking of using some hideous hacks in unit tests for this..

## Possible interesting links

- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1773